# How to find a system of linear equations in $w$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that its solutions are

Tags: linear-algebra

> (4) Find a system of linear equations in $w$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that its solutions are $$\begin{bmatrix} w\\x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\2\\3 \end{bmatrix} +t \begin{bmatrix} 2\\3\\4\\5 \end{bmatrix}$$

I guess the first step is to solve for $t$ but there are too many variables here and all I know is to put the first column to the left.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{w-1}2=\frac{x+1}3=\frac{y-2}4=\frac{z-3}5(=t).$$

Comment: this is what i have done, and what would be the next step?

Comment: @KelvinCheung: don't you see that this is the solution ?

Comment: oh... i thought t has to be a number. Thank you.